# What causes a TX overrun, and how to troubleshoot?

Tags: linux, tunnel, ifconfig

On a Linux machine acting as a router I have a large number of TX 'overruns'.

The machine routes through a tunnel interface (which is where the overruns are occuring).  What would cause these overruns, and how could one troubleshoot such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Overruns occur when the NIC is queuing frames faster than the kernel can process them.

[Redhat: Common Queue Issues](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-network-common-queue-issues.html)

Comment: Now to find out why it is only happening on my nodes with bonding... http://xkcd.com/979/